# How do I make a Java function that retries a URL connection every half second if the connection takes too long?

Tags: java, urlconnection

So I have a problem with a Java program I have. The program's basic functionality includes basically connecting to a web API for data. The function that does that is something like this:

```
public static Object getData(String sURL) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(sURL);
    URLConnection request = url.openConnection();

    request.connect();

    return request.getContent();
}
```

The code works fine as it is, but recently, after my house changed ISPs, I have found that sometimes the connections take an unreasonably long amount of time, something like 10 seconds or more in about 10% of attempts, while the other 90% takes only around 200ms. I have found it to be faster to ask my program to call the function again in a different thread than to wait for some of these connections to finally connect.

Therefore, I want to change the function so that if after 500ms, the connection did not establish, it would disconnect and a new connection would be attempted. How could I do this?

Somewhere online I read that HttpURLConnection might help, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Search [the documentation of URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLConnection.html) for methods with the word `Timeout` in their names.

Answer (score 3):

`URLConnection` allows you to specify the connect and read timeout prior to calling `connect()`:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int)

> Sets a specified timeout value, in milliseconds, to be used when
>   opening a communications link to the resource referenced by this
>   URLConnection. If the timeout expires before the connection can be
>   established, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised. A timeout of
>   zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

With 500ms timeout:

```
try {
    URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
    request.setConnectTimeout(500); // 500 ms
    request.connect();
    // on successful connection
} catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
    // on request timeout
}
```

This you can pack into a loop, but I recommend limiting the number of attempts made.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try this out, I'm pretty sure this is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Java's URLConnection doesn't have retry capabilities in Java 8 therefore the best way here to achieve this - use an appropriate standalone 3-party library such as [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/index.html).
This is by far the best standalone 3-party HTTP client with advanced capabilities as of 2020 and it's still maintained.

By default as of version 5.2.x Apache Http Client, Apache Http Client uses the default implementation of `org.apache.http.client.HttpRequestRetryHandler`, which retries 3 times, but you can use a custom implementation instead.

The configuration might look like this(full imports are for example's sake):

```java
org.apache.http.client.HttpClient httpClient = org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.custom()
.setRetryHandler(YourCustomImplOfTheRetryHandlerClass)
//other config
.build();
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way I can reproduce that problem using my ISP.
I suggest you dig deeper into the problem and find a better solution. Sending another request just doesn't seem good enough to me. Maybe try a different way to get the data and see if that works for you. Can't say for sure as I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1) This is'nt an answer to asked question. 2) Syaing something is "not good enough for you" without providing alternatives is not even a constructive critique. Maybe you can include some sort of suggestion to improve the answer?

Comment: Fair enough. I found a tutorial on an alternative way to fetch data from a URL.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html
This method could not help at all, but it's worth a shot. I can't say for sure as I can't reproduce the problem, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Network connections like to play tricks. I think an answer to this one is to set up a connection with low timeout, and maybe use automatic retries. The *real* solution would be of course fixing the lower level networking problem. Anyway, I don't think the original question had anything to do with *reading* from a connection, just establishing one.